# Setting up YouTrack on custom subdomain on Ubuntu 14.04 with Plesk Onyx 17.5

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, plesk, youtrack

I want to set up YouTrack standalone on my webserver using the [zip-Version](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Install-YouTrack-ZIP-Installation.html).

I've uploaded and extracted all files on my server and I've created a subdomain (board.domain.de). Then I've configured YouTrack wo use another base url and to listen to another port:

```
./youtrack.sh configure --listen-port 1111 --base-url https://board.domain.de:2222
```

This is the output:

```
* Configuring JetBrains YouTrack 2018.1 
* Setting property 'listen-port' to '1111' from arguments 
* Setting property 'base-url' to 'https://board.domain.de:2222' from arguments 
* JetBrains YouTrack 2018.1 runtime environment is successfully configured 
* Loading logging configuration from /var/www/vhosts/domain.de/board.domain.de/youtrack-2018/lib/ext/log4j.xml 
* Redirecting JetBrains YouTrack 2018.1 logging to /var/www/vhosts/domain.de/board.domain.de/youtrack-2018/logs/internal/services/bundleProcess 
* Configuring Service-Container[bundleProcess] 
* Configuring Bundle Backend Service 
* Configuring Configuration Wizard
```

Then I've started YouTrack via `./youtrack.sh start` which worked fine without any errors. Output:

```
Starting YouTrack...
* Configuring JetBrains YouTrack 2018.1 
* JetBrains YouTrack 2018.1 runtime environment is successfully configured 
* Loading logging configuration from /var/www/vhosts/domain.de/board.domain.de/youtrack-2018/lib/ext/log4j.xml 
* Redirecting JetBrains YouTrack 2018.1 logging to /var/www/vhosts/domain.de/board.domain.de/youtrack-2018/logs/internal/services/bundleProcess 
* Configuring Service-Container[bundleProcess] 
* Configuring Bundle Backend Service 
* Configuring Configuration Wizard 
* Starting Service-Container[bundleProcess] 
* Starting Bundle Backend Service 
* Starting Configuration Wizard 
* JetBrains YouTrack 2018.1 Configuration Wizard will be available on [https://board.domain.de:2222/?wizard_token=7bDc4UyhjyLFPmlJhkzm] after start 
YouTrack is running
```

Clicking on the shown url, my browser opens but shows me an error. Website not reachable (`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`). I thinks this has something to do with my apache/nginx configuration. So I've followed [these instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Reverse-Proxy-Configuration.html#Configure_Headers).

So, in Plesk under my subdomain-settings I've edited the common apache settings:

[image]

But I still get the error from above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide related records from Apache and nginx logs? `/var/www/vhosts/system/domain.de/board.domain.de/error_log`, `/var/www/vhosts/system/domain.de/board.domain.de/proxy_error_log`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in using **https** in base URL.
Apache config doesn't contain lines required for enabling TLS mode:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile <path_to_certificate>
SSLCertificateKeyFile <path_to_key>
```

This way proxy listen to plain http traffic on port 2222 while browser tries to establish secure connection.

See [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Reverse-Proxy-Configuration.html) for mode details